# How to use EF Core migrations in Windows Service?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core, windows-services

Hello i am trying to implement a Windows Service which needs EF Core migrations. Here's my DbContext inheritor:

```
public sealed class ExchangeContext : DbContext
{
    public const string SchemaName = "Exchange";
    
    public ExchangeContext(DbContextOptions<ExchangeContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    
    ...
    
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder
            .ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    }
}
```

My Program.cs file seems like this:

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args) =>
        Host
            .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureServices((_, services) =>
            {
                var configuration = services 
                    .BuildServiceProvider() 
                    .GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();

                services
                    .AddApplicationServices()
                    .AddInfrastructureServices(configuration);
            })
            .UseWindowsService() 
            .Build() 
            .Run();
}
```

I register DbContext using following logic:

```
...

.AddDatabaseContext<ExchangeContext>(
                    configuration,
                    DatabaseProvider.SqlServer,
                    false,
                    ExchangeContextConnectionStringSectionKey,
                    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName)

...

namespace AsCore.Infrastructure.Persistence.EntityFrameworkCore
{
    public static class EntityFrameworkCoreConfiguration
    {
        private const string SqlServerTag = "SqlServerConnection";
        private const string PostgreSQLTag = "PostgreSQLConnection";
        
        public static IServiceCollection AddDatabaseContext<TContext>(this IServiceCollection services,
            IConfiguration configuration,
            DatabaseProvider provider,
            bool useHealthCheck,
            string connectionStringSectionName,
            string migrationAssemblyName = null) where TContext : DbContext
        {
            var connectionString = configuration
                .GetConnectionString(connectionStringSectionName);
            
            var databaseContextOptionsAction = CreateContextOptions(provider,
                connectionString,
                migrationAssemblyName);
            
            return services
                .AddDbContext<TContext>(databaseContextOptionsAction)
                .ConfigureHealthChecks<TContext>(useHealthCheck,
                    provider,
                    connectionString);
        }
        
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseMigrationsOfContext<TContext>(this IApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder)
            where TContext : DbContext
        {
            using var serviceScope = applicationBuilder
                .ApplicationServices
                .CreateScope();

            var databaseContext = serviceScope
                .ServiceProvider
                .GetService<TContext>();

            var isInvalid = databaseContext is null;

            if (isInvalid)
            {
                var errorMessage =
                    $"{nameof(UseMigrationsOfContext)}: {typeof(TContext).FullName}";

                throw new ArgumentException(errorMessage);
            }

            databaseContext
                .Database
                .Migrate();

            return applicationBuilder;
        }

        private static Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder> CreateContextOptions(DatabaseProvider provider,
            string connectionString,
            string migrationAssemblyName = null) =>
                provider switch
                {
                    DatabaseProvider.SqlServer => migrationAssemblyName != null
                        ? (Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder>) (optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder
                            .UseSqlServer(connectionString,
                                sqlServerOptionsBuilder =>
                                    sqlServerOptionsBuilder.MigrationsAssembly(migrationAssemblyName)))
                        : (DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) => optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString),
                    DatabaseProvider.PostgreSQL => migrationAssemblyName != null
                        ? (Action<DbContextOptionsBuilder>) (optionsBuilder => optionsBuilder
                            .UseNpgsql(connectionString,
                                postgresOptionsBuilder =>
                                    postgresOptionsBuilder.MigrationsAssembly(migrationAssemblyName)))
                        : (DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) => optionsBuilder.UseNpgsql(connectionString),
                    _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(DatabaseProvider))
                };

        private static IServiceCollection ConfigureHealthChecks<TContext>(this IServiceCollection services,
            bool useHealthCheck,
            DatabaseProvider provider,
            string connectionString) where TContext : DbContext
        {
            if (!useHealthCheck)
            {
                return services;
            }

            return services
                .AddDatabaseHealthChecks<TContext>(
                    provider,
                    connectionString);
        }

        private static IServiceCollection AddDatabaseHealthChecks<TContext>(this IServiceCollection services,
            DatabaseProvider provider,
            string connectionString) where TContext : DbContext =>
                provider switch
                {
                    DatabaseProvider.SqlServer => services
                        .AddHealthChecks()
                        .AddSqlServer(connectionString,
                            name: typeof(TContext).FullName,
                            tags: new[] { SqlServerTag })
                        .Services,
                    DatabaseProvider.PostgreSQL => services
                        .AddHealthChecks()
                        .AddNpgSql(connectionString,
                            name: typeof(TContext).FullName,
                            tags: new[] { PostgreSQLTag })
                        .Services,
                    _ => throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(DatabaseProvider))
                };
    }
}
```

The registry works properly for sure (used the way many many times). I am trying the create the initial migration with the following command: 'dotnet ef migrations add CreatedInitialSchema --startup-project ../SharePricePredictor -o ./Persistence/Migrations --verbose'. Unfortunately i get the following error: 'Unable to create an object of type 'ExchangeContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
---> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContextOptions`1[SharePricePredictor.Infrastructure.Persistence.Context.ExchangeContext]' while attempting to activate 'SharePricePredictor.Infrastructure.Per
sistence.Context.ExchangeContext'.'. How to solve such an issue? What am i doing wrong? Thanks for any answer.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the EF tool is not able to recognize a `DBContext` to run from. It usually happens when the `DbContext` is in a project (`.csproj`) different from the application's entry point. As you're running an external command (`dotnet ef`), the DI container will not be ready yet, it'll be ready only for the run time. As the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dbcontext-creation?tabs=dotnet-core-cli#from-a-design-time-factory) saids, try to create a design-time factory in the same project as `ExchangeContext`:

```
public class ExchangeContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ExchangeContext>
{
    public ExchangeContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var appSettingsPath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "relative-path-to-your-appsettings-file");

        var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(appSettingsPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();

        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ExchangeContext>();
        builder.UseSqlServer(
            configuration
                .GetConnectionString("SqlServer") // In your case, the section referring to "ExchangeContextConnectionStringSectionKey"
        );

        return new ExchangeContext(builder.Options);
    }
}
```

> Note: prior to EFCore 5.0 the args parameter was unused

make the necessary changes to meet your needs. The above class purpose is to declare explicitly how your `DBContext` should be constructed. The tool will bypass the other ways of creating the `DbContext` and use the design-time factory instead. To run the migration, type the command below:

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate --context ExchangeContext --project ExchangeContextProjectName
```